# Datatype of variable in ada

Tags: ada

How can I find the datatype of a variable in Ada?

For example, given

```
INT : integer;
```

how can I print "the datatype is integer" for this variable?

In Python, `type()` can be used to find the type. Is there any similar function in Ada to find the datatype of a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ada is a strongly typed language, and when you declare a variable you specify its type.  So there is no use for a function to return the variable's type, as there would be in languages with untyped variables.  The program already knows the type.

If a variable `X` is declared with type `T'Class`, then the type of the actual value can be `T` or any type derived from `T`.  In that case, you can use `X'Tag` to get the *tag* of the value's actual type, which is the closest you can come to getting the actual type.  Once you have a tag, you can do things like getting the type's name (there are functions for this in `Ada.Tags`), comparing it to the tag of some type to see if it's that type, etc.  But `Integer` is not a tagged type, so you can't use `'Tag` on it and there would be no use for it.

Comment: You can also check `Classwide_Instance in Derived_Type’Class` to see whether the instance is of type `Derived_Type` (or of one of its derived types, of course, if there are any).

Comment: "As there would be in languages with untyped variables." C# is considered to be a strongly typed language, yet you can use "is" operator to test if an object is of a certain type and typeof() to get its type. This vary useful when using polymorphic types. Let's say you have a bunch of, say Shape objects, and you want to determine whether if they are squares, circles or triangles. Without it, you have to assign a explicit "kind" to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `INT` as a *Integer*, it will always be a *Integer* in that scope.
So you could just make a function like:

```
function the_type(I : Integer) return String is ("Integer");
```

I can't think of a reason you would want to check the type of variable `INT` if it always going to be a *Integer*.

On the other hand if `INT` can change type at run-time you will need code to emulate that:

```
procedure Main is
    type Memory_Type_Enum is (Integer_Type, Float_Type);

    record Variable
        Memory_Location : Address;
        Memory_Type : Memory_Type_Enum;
    end record;

    INT : Variable;
begin
    INT := Allocate_Variable(Float_Type);
    INT := Allocate_Variable(Integer_Type);
    Put_Line(INT.Memory_Type'Img);
end;
```

But it's up to you how you implement a type check whether you have dynamic type system or static.